# How to exclude sending SMS on holidays?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sms, holidays

I am setting up a journey with external API system in SFMC to send SMS message and have a situation of recurring journey running daily, taking all records from Call object who made a call the day before and sending them SMS. The problem I need to solve is how to exclude the SMS going on the holiday (if the call happened on the day before the holiday) and send those contacts SMS the day after the holiday

Comment: If you had to break down the problem into small chunks what would they be? Could you plot out the steps between receiving a the API call and sending the message later?

Comment: my initial set up is: forming the audience for send through SQL queries in automation studio (referencing call object with a daily run- so including weekends and holidays to get those contacts in the audinece); second step is in joureny builder where I have a data extension as entry source, recurring jorueny (on weekdays to avoid weekends) and then the API tool SMS activity and I am thinking about somehow incorporating decision split to split people to either wait 1 day or get SMS immediately but here I have a problem on how to form the split incorporating holiday dates